# What's the easiest way to merge video, audio and image files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ffmpeg

We are planning a Wep App for a Hackathon that's happening in about 2 weeks.
The app basic functions are:

- The users are guided step-by-step to upload a video, audio and image.
- The image is used as a cover for the audio. Making it into a video file.
- The two video files are **merged** thus creating a **single** video from the initial three files.

So, my problem is:

1. How do you create a video from an audio with an image as "cover".
2. How do you merge this two videos.

We are thinking of using Heroku for deployment. Is there a way to do it using something like [stremio](https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg)?

What would be the best approach? A VPS running a C++ script? How's the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

FFMPEG would be a good start as seen here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6087453/1258001

FFMPEG can be found at http://ffmpeg.org/

Also another option that maybe over kill would be Blender 3d as it could also provide simular results and could be controlled via shell commands and maybe more flexible in terms of complexe needs for asset compositions.

In any case your gonna want a server that can run heavy rendering processes wich will require a large amount of ram and cpu processing. It maybe a good choice to go with a render farm that can run gpu as the main processor for rendering as that will give you more bang for your buck but could be very difficult to set up and kept running correctly. I would also say a VPS would not be a good choice for this. In any case the type of resources your gonna need also so happen to be the most expensive in terms of web server costs. Best of luck please update with your results.